# How to chose all rows where there are at least two same values within the subset

Tags: sql, sql-server

New in SQL looks hard for me. For example I have a table with two columns.

```
page_session_id, event_name
```

Let say I want to chose all rows where there are at least two event_name = 'started' within the same page_session_id

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd expect from it?

Comment: google-learn about the "GROUP BY", "HAVING" and "COUNT" functions in SQL Server.   They are all you need to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with HAVING:

```
select 
    page_session_id, event_name
from tbl 
where event_name = 'started'
group by page_session_id, event_name
having count(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one row and want to get all the columns from the table, you can use this

```
;with cte as (
   select
       *,
       count(*) over(partition by page_session_id) as cnt
   from <table>
   where event_name = 'started'
)
select *
from cte
where cnt > 1
```